# Using FLOOR() in WHERE clause in MySQL

Tags: mysql, where-clause, floor

Is it possible to use `FLOOR()` in a `WHERE` clause, and if so, could someone tell me why the below code is wrong?

I have understood a lot from research on what it is and how to use it, but I cannot find anything which could fix this error.

```
select * from medications 
where floor(datediff('d', date(update_time) – date(insert_time))) <=1
```

My intention is to pull all records which have been amended in the last X number of days, where X <= 1 in this case.

Having readdressed it and considered people's comments below, I have decided to just use the code below.  I hadn't really understood `FLOOR()` well enough to use it. The one below works for me.

```
m.updt_time >= (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 day))
```

It substitutes the number of days for a Crystal Reports parameter.

Comment: Give an error that are you got?

Comment: Perhaps there is something I am missing... but how can a date difference give you a float number and you need `floor()`? Won't the result always be an integer?

Comment: Right now, you are not even using `datediff` correctly ... that function expects two date or datetime values. Passing `'d'` as first parameter makes no sense, and `date` returns something in the form YYYY-MM-DD - “subtracting” two of those values from another does not make sense either. `datediff` used correctly would return an integer value anyway, so you don’t need floor anywhere here.

Comment: @CBroe exactly! Mike, you need construct your DB and logic better. I fear your DB fields which store the dates are not even of proper type.

Comment: Exactly. And even if the value returned was a float, the expression doesnt need a floor() to round it because the final aim is to check if it's smaller or equal to something. Thus `floor(0.12)<=1` returns the same results as `0<=1` and `0.12<=1`. Conclusion: this query is plain wrong.

Comment: It looks like you need to read about the [MySQL functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/functions.html).

Comment: I was given the code by someone who has considerably more coding experience than me, i i was assuming it was something i was missing for it to not be working.  I hadn't considered that it was wrong until now.  I have decided to readdress it and use the code added to the original question as an edit.

Comment: Thanks for your help all the same.  As a noob it is always nice to feel encouraged and that people appreciate that not everyone who comes to this site is a super coder.............

Comment: You should put the solution as an Answer Your Own Question, so this can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having readdressed it and considered people's comments below, I have decided to just use the code below. I hadn't really understood FLOOR() well enough to use it. The one below works for me.

```
m.updt_time >= (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 day))
```

I substitute the number of days for a Crystal Reports parameter.